# Gate fold leaflet - How to set up indesign document?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, document-setup

There are no presets for creating a gate fold leaflet in InDesign. What is the best way to set one up? The size of the leaflet will be A5 when closed.

The attached image shows an example of what I'm after.

[image: Gate fold leaflet example]
<sub>(source: [cedargraphicsinc.com](https://www.cedargraphicsinc.com/portals/1/Templates/folding/GateFold_2Parallel_OC_2.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Are you unable to set up the document, with the sizes as shown?  I don't understand what your problem is. Can't you use guides?

Comment: I am able to set up the document with the sizes shown, but I'm trying to set it up so that they're all displayed as separate pages so it's easier to set up margins, columns etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 page document with one page being the inside and other being the outside.

**I'd set it up like this:**

1. 2 page document.

   - Inside page and outside page.
2. 2 guides to divide each page in 3 sections <sup><sub>(the two dashed lines in your example image)</sub></sup>.

   - It's only two pages, but I would still draw the guides on a Master page. Less work and they automatically become untouchable.
   - I would draw a rectangle with the width 4.25" to the left side and copy that to the other side. That way it's easy to just snap the guides to each side of the page. Then the rectangles can be thrown away.

---

Or if you want to have each section as its own page you could do the following:

- In the Pages panel, either by right-clicking any of the pages or in the corner menu uncheck `Allow document pages to shuffle`.
- Then you can drag pages side by side.
- When you export you need to make sure the `Export as` is set to `Spreads` or if you print straight from Indesign you need to make sure `Sequence` is set to `Spreads`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suppose I could set it up like you said. however, I was wondering whether there is a way to set up InDesign so that it displays each page as a separate page as this would be useful for setting up margins, columns etc.

Comment: @RubenKretek, I don't see it as necessary, but it is possible. I appended instructions in my answer.

Comment: @RubenKretek, I realize I mayhaps assumed too much and left out a few details that I figured you didn't need. Let me know if you need me to elaborate...

Comment: No that's fine thanks. Your answer is perfect!